# how to use the original servlet to redirect In a struts2 method

Tags: struts2, servlet-3.0

In a Struts2 method，i organize the url which i want redirect,but i can't use the url in the struts.xml, so want use the original servlet to redirect.In fact,the struts2 method ask return a String Type,if i use original servlet to redirect,how to handle the method return.3q.

```
public String qqLogin() throws IOException, QQConnectException {
    getResponse().setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
    String authorizeURL = new Oauth().getAuthorizeURL(getRequest());
    log.info("LoginAction#qqLogin -> authorizeURL：" + authorizeURL);
    getResponse().sendRedirect(authorizeURL);
    return "";}
```

Comment: Are you looking for this -> https://struts.apache.org/docs/parameters-in-configuration-results.html?

Comment: @Aleksandr M  Your comment is  useful to me,but use the way of struts docs,it can only redirect the same webapp.In fact, i want to redirect another address,just like `https://www.google.com`,can you offer some advice?3q.

Comment: Use `redirect` result.